# How to sort nested dictionary in python?

Tags: python, algorithm, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary in my project:

```
>>> dict = {
    "content": """<p>It is common for content in Arabic, Hebrew, and other languages that use right-to-left scripts to include numerals or include text from  other scripts. Both of these typically flow  left-to-right within the overall right-to-left  context. </p>""", 
    "name": "directory", 
    "decendent": [
         {
            "content": """<p>This article tells you how to write HTML where text with different writing directions is mixed <em>within a paragraph or other HTML block</em> (ie. <dfn id="term_inline">inline or phrasal</dfn> content). (A companion article <a href="/International/questions/qa-html-dir"><cite>Structural markup and right-to-left text in HTML</cite></a> tells you how to use HTML markup for  elements such as <code class="kw">html</code>, and structural markup such as <code class="kw">p</code> or <code class="kw">div</code> and forms.)</p>""", 
            "name": "subdirectory", 
            "decendent": None
        }, 
        {
            "content": """It tells you how to use HTML markup for  elements such as <code class="kw">html</code>, and structural markup such as <code class="kw">p</code> or <code class="kw">div</code> and forms.)""", 
            "name": "subdirectory_two", 
            "decendent": [
                {
                    "content": "Name 4", 
                    "name": "subsubdirectory", 
                    "decendent": None
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and a function which generates it:

```
def getname(dirpath):
    onlyfile = [entry for entry in os.listdir(dirpath) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dirpath, entry)) and entry.endswith(".txt")][0]
    onlyfilename = os.path.join(dirpath, onlyfile)

    decendent = []
    for entry in os.listdir(dirpath):
        entrypath = os.path.join(dirpath, entry)
        if os.path.isfile(entrypath):
            continue
        decendent.append(getname(entrypath))

    if len(decendent) == 0:
        decendent = None

    return {'name': onlyfilename.split("/")[-2],
            'path': onlyfilename.rsplit("/", 1)[-2] + "/index.html",
            'leaf': readFile(onlyfilename),
            'decendent': decendent}
```

The problem is that it returns an unordered set of dictionaries as descendents:

[image]

How to sort them in my case when they're nested?

Comment: You have an *ordered list* of dictionaries (not an unordered `set`, something entirely different). Lists can be sorted, so just sort the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `descendent` value is *just a list*. Lists can be sorted, no matter where they are referenced. That it is inside a dictionary doesn't matter here.

Your `descendent` list order is set by whatever order `os.listdir()` returns. You can sort that, or you can simply sort the `descendent` object itself. Sort by using a [natural sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort) for example, or use any other criteria for your sorting.

Using the `natural_sort()` function from [Mark Byer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4836734) on the `os.listdir()` result, for example:

```
for entry in natural_sort(os.listdir(dirpath)):
```

would list your directory entries in a sorted order for you to insert into the `descendant` list.